Undamaged tire repeatedly deflating
I have a tire that repeatedly deflates from 35 to 27 PSI (which is when the light comes on) after only 2-3 weeks. After being unable to find a puncture using a tub with water, I had the tire reinstalled on the rim thinking it is likely the rim seal that was compromised. That wasn't it and I replaced the schrader valve core. Now that is also not the cause because it just re-deflated.
At this point I am starting the think the rim is damaged so the tire cannot possibly form a tight seal. But replacing the rim would be more expensive than a tire. What is more likely, according to your experience and educated guessing, to be the cause at this point?

Did you have the tire shop check for a leak?

no, i did it myself but maybe getting someone else to also look might not be a bad idea

First of all, measure the pressure regularly (daily or even twice a day) and plot the results to see if this is a steady slow leak or isolated events (e.g. every morning when the tire is in the sun, or every time you drive the car, or every Friday night when a neighbourhood prankster walks by on their way back from the bar).

You're measuring it with a gauge or taking the TPMS measurements?

with a gauge...

Where I'm from (UK), tyre shops will check for leaks for free, assuming that if you needed a new tyre, you would probably use them. I can't imagine it would be much more expensive around your neck of the woods. (Yes, yes, some unscrupulous actors might claim you need a new tyre anyway, but if the problem persists, they have been proven false.)

There are many possible sources of your air leak: cracked rim, dirty or damaged rim seal, or a leak in the tire itself. What is most likely is you haven't used the right method for finding the leak. Submerging it in water isn't the way to go, use a spray bottle filled with dishsoapy water and systematically spray that wheel everywhere. Get it into every nook and cranny of every tread, along the rim seal, the valve and stem, and the rim itself. You'll see bubbles forming where the leak is.
You can't do the whole thing at once, so use a dry erase marker to mark the areas where you have tested as you go.

This has always worked for me. But sometimes with a very small leak, moving bubbles could not be seen right away. If you don't see immediate moving bubbles, come back in 5 minutes or so and look again. For small leaks like this, it's best to have the wheel off the vehicle.

In addition to @GdD's good advice, be aware that a valve stem could possibly leak only when the wheel is spinning. I had that once. No leak whatsoever from a static wheel, but the centrifugal force from the spinning wheel forced the valve stem to lean slightly outward, and then it would leak. So try some soapy water around the base of the valve stem, and push the stem in all directions to see if that creates bubbles.
Another possibility if these are alloy wheels is that the casting is porous and air is leaking directly through the metal. There are sealants for that.

With the valve stem, also check the valve core for leaks. It could just be lose.

The alloy wheels on one car I had would need the valve seatings cleaning every few years, after slow leaks developed that were not punctures.

Do you have a patient practical joker friend or angry neighbor? Had this happen once.

The test here might be to swap wheels around the vehicle and see if the deflation follows the rim, or stays in the same corner of the car.

Reminds me of the guy who was proud of the gas economy of his car (before locking gas caps) and the prankster would add gas to his tank so that his numbers looked fantastic, then one day he stopped.

I had a tire that would loose air/go flat all the time.
Had the the garage check it, remount it and change the tire valve.
After years of putting air in it at home, One day I forgot to put the valve cap back on and lost it.
Two/three years later, I put air in it maybe once or twice to top it off since I lost the cap.
No one has any idea why.  No small stones/stuff in the cap.

I have (aluminum alloy) rims that can take months to slowly leak to where it's noticeable, and it is worse during the cold months.  That's so slow/intermittent that I'd bet a shop wouldn't be able to find anything.  Every time I have the shop wire-brush the rims and re-seal the bead with some goop, the problem disappears for X years.
Edit: And it wouldn't surprise me if hitting just the right pothole at the right angle could bring the problem back.
